# Using CardView in Android 5.0 release in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-cardview

Are the hacks posted previously still needed in order to use the CardView and RecyclerView libraries in Eclipse even with the 5.0 SDK release?

http://happilycoded.com/blog/using-recyclerview-and-cardview-in-eclipse-adt/

(In fact, this one no longer seems to work because the m2repository no longer exists)

What's the easiest way to use these libraries in Eclipse?

EDIT:

In Eclipse:

"File->Import->Existing Projects into Workspace" only lists

v7-appcompat, v7-gridlayout, v7-mediarouter, v7-palette

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are the hacks posted previously still needed in order to use the CardView and RecyclerView libraries in Eclipse even with the 5.0 SDK release?

No. You will find `recyclerview` and `cardview` Android library projects in the `extras/android/support/v7/` directory in your Android SDK installation, assuming that you are up-to-date on those from the SDK Manager. Those should be importable into Eclipse, at which point you would reference them from your app as you would any other Android library project.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but when I do an Import from the top-level of v7 the only projects available are:

appcompat, gridlayout, mediarouter, palette.  You have CardView and RecyclerView available for Import?  I see them as folders, but they're not showing up as Eclipse projects.  I now wonder if my SDK install is corrupt..

Comment: @Alchete: "but they're not showing up as Eclipse projects" -- they are not Eclipse projects. Use the Android import, not the Eclipse import option (Android > Import existing Android code, or something like that, in the Import dialog).

Comment: Ahh!  Thank you Mark!!  I had been importing the other compat libraries as Eclipse projects without issue, these two *need* to be imported as Android projects.  My mistake.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Alchete: I filed [an enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77716) to get all the projects synchronized in terms of having Eclipse project files. In general, I'd recommend using the Android project import process, as that always works, taking advantage of the Eclipse project files if they exist and creating them if they do not exist.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select the latest Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, and
   Build-tools.
2. Select latest Android Support Library & Android Support
   Repository.
3. After updating Android Support Repository from SDK
   Manager go
   to..\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\21.0.0-rc1
4. Unzip recyclerview-v7-21.0.0-rc1.aar
5. After unzipping recyclerview-v7-21.0.0-rc1.aar you will get classes.jar
6. rename classes.jar to recyclerView.jar for feature reference and add to
   your Android app under /lib folder

Similar way even for cardView.

Comment: Yes, Uninstall of L Preview will remove the recycler and CardView folder from m2repository

Comment: Yes, sorry.  The m2repository folder appears when you install the "Android Support Repository".  However, is this still the only way to import these two libraries into Eclipse?  CommonsWare says differently, but I can't Import the CardView and RecyclerView libraries as normal projects.  Anyone else having luck with a straight Eclipse->Import Existing Projects?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan: Your technique will not handle the resources in those library projects and therefore will not work for `cardview-v7`. It appears that `recyclerview-v7` has no resources in its current implementation, so your approach would work for it for now. But my guess is that Google intends to add resources to `recyclerview-v7` sometime in the future.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes you're right. Since it is developer release they have given this approach, may be in-future it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an old version eclipse. I have the same problem and I've done. Here are some tips. I hope it can help you.

1.Open the Android SDK Manager.
2.Update Android SDK Tools first.
3.Update Android SDK Platform-tools.
4.In the end, Update Android Support Library.